# Cómo leer MySQL con vue.js igual que con Ajax

Tags: mysql, vue.js

Les cuento mi interrogante, tengo una base de datos en MySQL en dónde cada minuto guardo información de sensores y tengo una página en dónde utilizo Ajax con el método async para leer los últimos registros guardados en la base de datos. Todo funciona perfecto, pero me gustaría saber si se puede hacer lo mismo con vue.js, lo que he podido hacer es leer la base de datos con

```
methods:{
        get_datos_sensores (){
            fetch("./conexion.php")
        se de datos cada 30 segundos y ver  .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(json=>{this.all_data=json.sensores})
        }
```

Pero no Lee los datos de forma recurrente como lo hace Ajax. Entonces me gustaría saber si se puede o no hacerlo con vue.js también. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No comprendo tu pregunta, quizás por terminología, pero si usas `fetch()`, en realidad estás usando Ajax, y nada impide que uses Ajax con Vue o con cualquier otro framework.  Así que, si te funciona con Ajax, pues, sigue usándolo con Vue.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Me parece que estas confundido.. podrias clarificar el problema que tuviste en vue para hacer un fetch.. porque basicamente, vue reemplaza tu js+html por algo mas comodo (seria igual en react, angular o cualquier otro)...

Comment: Es mas.. me parece que confundiste ajax con un js que haga llamadas a intervalos regulares.. lo cual podes hacer en vue sin problemas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a hacer esto, el setInterval llama al método cada 30 segundos.
Y luego beforeDestroy se limpia el intervalo.

```
data() {
    return {
        intervalId: null,
        all_data: []
    }
},
methods:{
    get_datos_sensores (){
        fetch("./conexion.php")
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(json=>{this.all_data=json.sensores})
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.get_datos_sensores, 30000); // 30000 milisegundos son 30 segundos
},
beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId); 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me fue de mucha utilidad.